# Combine similar array information into a Json

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have two different `Json` files, each generated from a different php array. They both contain one piece of similar information that I want to link together in one document.

`Php array one` looks like this:

```
$HisNameIsMyName = array(
    'His' => 'John',
    'Name' => 'Jacob',
    'Is' => 'Jacob',
    'My' => 'Jacob',
    'Name2' => 'Shmidt');
```

And was converted into `Json` via the following code:

```
$compiled = json_decode(file_get_contents('compiled.json'), true);
foreach ($HisNameIsMyName as $word => $publisher) {
    $compiled[$word]['publisher'] = $publisher;
}
file_put_contents('compiled.json', json_encode($compiled, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
```

And output the following:

```
{
    "His": {
        "publisher": "John"
    },
    "Name": {
        "publisher": "Jacob"
    },
    "Is": {
        "publisher": "Jacob"
    },
    "My": {
        "publisher": "Jacob"
    },
    "Name2": {
        "publisher": "Shmidt"
    }
}
```

Each `Publisher` has been assigned a number in a different array and looks like the following:

```
$numberToPublisher = array(
    "John" => 1,
    "Jacob" => 2,
    "Jingle" => 3,
    "Himer" => 4,
    "Shmidt" => 5
```

How would I take the number assigned to the `Publisher` in `$numberToPublisher` and add it to the `Json` so that it would look like the following:

```
{
    "His": {
        "publisher": "John"
        "pubNumber": "1"
    },
    "Name": {
        "publisher": "Jacob"
        "pubNumber": "2"
    },
    "Is": {
        "publisher": "Jacob"
        "pubNumber": "2"
    },
    "My": {
        "publisher": "Jacob"
        "pubNumber": "2"
    },
    "Name2": {
        "publisher": "Shmidt"
        "pubNumber": "5"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend your existing loop like this:

```
foreach ($HisNameIsMyName as $word => $publisher) {
    $compiled[$word]['publisher'] = $publisher;
    $compiled[$word]['pubNumber'] = $numberToPublisher[$publisher];
}
```

Comment: Didn't think it could be that simple. Thanks!